# A way of using PS Spatter filter non-destructively on linework?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, smartobject, filter

Because the Spatter filter only functions on contiguous pixels, there is no simple way of applying it like a Smart Filter to a layer of line work.

I'm looking at the work of Kevin Dart, and trying to replicate that chalky line, but in such a way that I can tweak my linework separately to the spatter effect. I've got as far as using a Smart Object with black linework over a white background layer, then applying Spatter Smart Filter to the Smart Object.

But the next step would seem to be to use the Smart Object as a clipping mask. Except that I need to mask based on the Black/White layer mask method, because I have all my pixels opaque.

If I go turn off the white Background layer, the Spatter ceases to function.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think a sample image is needed, and perhaps paragraph breaks to make human reading easier (we are designers). From what I can gather, it would merely take a layer mask with the distressed texture on it.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of something like this, I usually duplicate the layer, hide the original and mess around with the copy. Only way I can think of to retain the original line art while still having the space to play in.

Comment: You mean rasterise the copy? Maybe that's the only way. If there was some non-destructive filter or blend mode I could apply that would create a 'live' alpha channel from the RGB, then I could use the S.O. as a clipping mask

Comment: I can't think of another off the top of my head. There may be a third-party filter out there.

Comment: Yeah there is a Filter Forge filter by Ayato, that works like Knoll UnMult, but I dont have FF

Answer (score 0):

I agree, we might need a sample image to see what exactly you're trying to achieve. I took a look at some of Kevin Dart's work, he's very talented!

Here's what I THINK might be happening. I think that Mr. Dart makes use of both Photoshop (PS) and Illustrator (AI) in conjunction. So he may create a vectorized scene and then make modifications in PS to create atmosphere or add details that maybe aren't as easy to achieve in AI.

I'm not sure if you have experience with AI, but brushes work a little differently than in PS. What you're looking at might actually be a vectorized brush that can only be practically achieved through AI.

Another thing you can do if you're more comfortable working with PS:

- Find a brush that you would be satisfied with in AI
- Save that one element as a separate file
- Import that element into your PS document

Alright, I hope that helps.

Good luck!

EDIT: I found this tutorial on his page: http://www.kevindart.com/images/tutorials/hdm01.html

This at least tells you what software he uses and his process during creation so it might be helpful!!

Comment: I hate these tutorials, they always make it seem so easy :) No seriously, great tutorial by an obviously very talented artist

Comment: Agreed!!

Tutorials should be more realistic if you ask me.

1. Set my brain on fire with an LSD fueled bender
2. Cry onto some paper while furiously stabbing at the paper
3. Enter the "self doubt stage". Afraid that while the bender was a great idea in theory, you're no closer to a functional design
4. Look at stab-sketches again and import
...
..
.
253. AMAZING MIND MELTING RESULTS.